# Looking for a way to on passively monitor file activity in a directory in Unix C++

Tags: c++, linux, posix, mutex

I have a thread I need to wake up when there is any disk-write (preferably on a specified directory). Currently I'm doing busy wait, which works, but I hoped that an interrupt will lower CPU consumption during sleep time.

The system is linux. I remember vaguely seeing such a library, but I can't find one now.
help, please?

Comment: Probably should remove c++ tag.

Comment: The title does not match the body of the question. If you wanted exclusive advisory locks on files, consider [flock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) or [lockf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) might do what you want.

Comment: Indeed, inotify. A great tool. Thanks!